# Iterating through columns in table using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, attribute-table, iterator

I am unable to find any info on how to use ModelBuilder to run a certain spatial analysis function on each column in a table.

I have a table to sample locations and at each location there are a series of measures (e.g. temperature, flow rate, number of certain species).  For each of those attributes (columns in the table), I was to run the IDW function from the surface tools.

This would be easy if I had each attribute in a separate shp/feature class, but not very efficient.  I tried Iterate Feature Selection, but was unable to pass the field name as the Z value in the IDW function.

This is for ArcGIS 10.1 (Basic and Spatial Analyst license)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you will need to build a small Python script and paste that into your Model. You would use the ArcPy module and build a field list on your layer:

```
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields("C:/Data/MyGIS.gdb/MyLayer")
```

and then you would iterate through the fieldList using a for loop, for example

```
for field in fieldList:
    #run your spatial analysis function on field
```

Comment: Thanks! The ListFields() is super handy. I took it out of model builder now and am trying to do it all in a Python script.  I had figure there would be an iterator for that, but it now gives me a good reason to work with Py.

Comment: I am also trying to do the exact same thing but having a hard time to make it work, can you share how you did it in Py or model builder?

Comment: This just helped me out with the Global Moran's I tool.  Worth adding that the field object in Arc has properties and tools may be after field.name rather than field.  They may also throw an error depending on the field.type.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "run your spatial analysis function on field" bit please? What shall be the script be like in ArcPy?

Comment: @AndrewLebron, regarding your previous post, Kernel Density is another function in `arcpy` which can be run through python interpreter in ArcGIS. For example `interim=arcpy.sa.KernelDensity("C:/Data/MyGIS.gdb/MyLayer",field.name,100,500,'SQUARE_KILOMETERS','EXPECTED_COUNTS')` will produce kernel density raster and assign to a temporary (as long as not saved) raster. Then you can save this as `interim.save(("C:/Data/MyGIS.gdb/MyLayer_Kernel_%s" %field.name)`.

Comment: Thanks @fatih_dur for the answer. The first code worked but I couldn't get the second one to work. And I have a question about the first one as well: the 3rd and 4th input (100 and 500) shall be the cell size and search radius right? I really don't know what to put for the search radius. The default (leaving it blank ) when running the tool works just fine. How can I do it when using Arcpy, as in leave it blank, fill in the default.

Comment: @fatih_dur and for the second code, I couldn't get it to work. Every time I put in %field.name part (like %Employment 01) it will say that it is not defined. When I just put in the interim.save(File Location), it says: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported. Could you help me here please? BTW, how shall I iterate in this way? Shall I do the fieldList first and then make the code interim=arcpy.sa.KernelDensity("File location",FieldList,100,500,'S‌​QUARE_KILOMETERS','E‌​XPECTED_COUNTS')? Thanks again.

Comment: @AndrewLebron, I think your problem has been resolved. For th records, you can look at this thread, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/interpretation-of-arcgis-kernel-density-legend-parameters, for more information about the optional aprameters of kernel density. And the second part, I am sorry about that, I did not pay attention to arcpy.ListFields, which returns all fields. You do not need to change `%field.name` since field variable here is `arcpy.Field` object and `name` is its attribute, which returns the object's name.

Comment: [CONTINUED] If you need to return specific fields for your analysis, you need to specify them, such as `fieldList = [f for f in arcpy.ListFields("C:/Data/MyGIS.gdb/MyLayer" if f.name.upper().startswith("C"))]`