# Iterate through all fields in attribute table and multiply by field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, table

I have a table with a whole bunch of census variables (race, age, education, etc). I want to multiply all of these fields by a factor that I calculated. For example:

Field1 has values of 10,20,30,40

Field2 has values of 120,340,230,210

Field3 has values of 500,3402,0342,9402

Multiplier field has values of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4

I want to 'iterate' through all the columns and multiply them by my multiplier field. Traditionally, I would use field calculator and do !Field1! * !Multiplier!, but I am trying to avoid having to do this for 200+ fields.

Any suggestions?

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: I think the first thing you will want to do is get a list of the fields you want to iterate through.  Then, once you have that list, a pretty simple python script can be put together to iterate through your list, and calculate your values using the [calculate field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) tool.

Comment: Where do you want to store this calcs? What do you expect to get? Single number per column?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/model-builder-iterate-through-columns-in-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each row has a value in the "Multiplier" field, by which you'd like to multiply the values in all of the other fields.

Field calculator only does one field at a time, though you could run it in batch mode.  For 200+ fields, I'd recommend some code like the following which uses a search cursor.  Put it in the python console.

```
layer = 'layername' #drag from TOC
multfield = "multiplier field name"

fieldnames = [i.name for i in arcpy.ListFields(layer) if not i.required]
ind = fieldnames.index(multfield) #now you know where it is in the list

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer,fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for n in range(len(fieldnames)):
            if n == ind:
                continue #don't update the multiplier field
            row[n] = row[n]*row[ind]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is assuming that you want to multiply *every* field by the multiplier, besides the multiplier itself, and any automatic fields like "OBJECTID".  If you have text fields, you'll get an error.