# Interpolating multiple years of daily precipitation data to generate daily time series?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, interpolation, precipitation, time-series

I am trying to use ArcMap ver. 10.2 to create several models using ModelBuilder. The model will be created to:

1. interpolate 7 years of point measured precipitation data (long integer format at a daily time step) using various surface-fitting methods (e.g. inverse distance weighting, polynomial, and kriging)
2. clip the output raster files to subbasins
3. do zonal stats on the clipped raster files
4. append the zonal stats into a table.

I have built the models, and they all run well (Fig. 1).

- The models only work for one day at a time. However, I need to run each model for over 2,000 iterations (one iteration for each day).
- I've tried using the iterator tools, but there is not a tool that will work with the way I have the attribute table set up (Fig. 1).
- I need to generate daily time series' of interpolated precipitation data by looping my models for multiple iterations.
- How can I make my models loop for multiple iterations, one iteration for each set of field values (i.e. column in attribute table)?

Additional background information follows:

The precipitation data are stored in a point file with a large attribute table. The attribute table has a field for each day precipitation was observed. The fields are labeled in sequence "PPT". Each field has multiple point measured daily precipitation values (long integer format), one point measurement for each location (n=10) where precipitation was measured.

[image]

Fig. 1. Model schematic and attribute table used to interpolate precipitation data.

Comment: You'll need a small script that takes iteration value (input) and return field name, e.g arcpy.ListFields("fish_net")[i].name

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible by combining models. You can just input your first iterating model into a second model that then iterates over these outputs. Here are some information about (at the top it shows that the help is available for 10.3 and 10.4. But it works in 10.2 as well. Its just the availability of the help page):

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. I don't understand what you mean by first iterating model, and second model.

Comment: Somehow i read an iteration to much. I thought you have one iterator already in the process of calculating the precipitation. So you have your model for one day ready? Then you just need to create the main model that has the iterator that runs for each day (the column with your integer day number) that iterates your submodel you already have.

Comment: Yes, I have the model for one day ready, but there is not an iterator tool that will iterate over multiple fields.

Comment: Here is an answer for iterating columns in model builder: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/iterating-through-columns-in-table-using-modelbuilder

Comment: Thank you, sir. That link was very helpful. I generated a script and ran into a different problem. I posted this problem as a different question. Hopefully, I can find some resolution to my problem. Here is the link: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190620/python-script-iterator-to-interpolate-accross-multiple-fields-of-attribute-table

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. The working script is located here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190620/python-script-iterator-to-interpolate-accross-multiple-fields-of-attribute-table