# Field calculating many fields in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, attribute-joins

I am trying to field calculate data between two large feature classes. I started to set up a model in ModelBuilder to do this until I thought I would ask if anyone has a better way to do this.

A brief description of the project: We have a large feature class of street center lines that have truck route information embedded to them. The routing information along with dates, and string fields need to be transferred to a property parcel feature class. There are about 50 or so fields that need to be transferred over.

What I have set up so far in model builder is two feature classes being joined and then 50 or so field calculate tools with a remove join at the end.

Does anyone know a more clever way to do this?

Comment: In python, with a for field in ['field1',..'field50']: . If you're not very comfortable with python just do the field calc as a script and embed that into your model. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/iterating-through-columns-in-table-using-modelbuilder

Comment: If you want to simplify your model you could try using sub-models. You would put your 50 calculations in a separate model then drop that model into your master model, thus making your master model easier to read. Instead of looking at 50 field calculate tools you see a single tool (which if you went inside would have 50 field calculates). Search the help file for "sub-model"

Comment: Do the fields have the same names across both shapefiles?

Comment: Yes they do. They are Feature Classes.

Comment: So far I have been creating the model in Model Builder. Because I am using a feature class (FC), I have to first use a tool called 'Make Feature Layer' to convert my FC into a layer. This is because after I join the two FC and run the field calculations the remove join tool only lets me un-join a layer or table, not a feature class. I am running tests and refining the model now.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro has [Calculate Field**s**](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-fields.htm), which will do exactly what you are looking for.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the sub-model technique and didn't have enough time to make it work for me. I just finished my model builder and although it doesn't look pretty it does the job and works fine.

[image: Field calculate for days!]